# I am trying to run kafka on windoes 10 but erros shows Error: Could not find or load main class Files\kafka\libs\activation-1.1.1.jar;C:\Program

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to install and run kafaka locally but it is showing the error it could no load activation class [image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have an unquoted path. Some where you have a path like `C:\Program Files\Path\To\File.jar`

It needs to be quoted as `"C:\Program Files\Path\To\File.jar"`

The other option is to put your Kafka installation into a simpler path e.g. `C:\kafka\...`

This is one of the old annoyances of Windows paths and some of the Apache Software Foundation "batch" files.

Comment: thank you for the answer,i tried the second option and it is working perfectly.

Comment: Try to add the quotes in your kafka configs.